# How to remove mobile layout from Joomla template?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-template

I use non-responsive Joomla template from Gavick.
For mobile, I started to use Jtouch.
There is a bug in the template, creating duplicate page.
Html is:

```
<div id="gkMainbodyWrap">                                                                       
    <div id="gkComponent">                  
    <gavern:desktop>
    <div class="item-page">
    // here is page code
   </gavern:desktop>

   <gavern:mobile>
   <div class="item-page">
    // ... here is the page content again !!! ...           
   </gavern:mobile>
```

I am trying to find what to delete from the template php file,
to stop this duplication.

Here is the relevant part of the php:

```
<div id="gkMainbody" class="gkMain">
    <div id="gkMainbodyWrap">
        <?php if($this->isFrontpage()) : ?>
            <?php if($this->getParam('mainbody_frontpage', 'only_component') == 'only_component') : ?>  
            <div id="gkComponent">
                <jdoc:include type="component" />
            </div>
            <?php elseif($this->getParam('mainbody_frontpage', 'only_component') == 'mainbody_before_component') : ?>
            <div id="gkComponent">
                <jdoc:include type="component" />
            </div>
            <?php else : ?>
            <div id="gkComponent">
                <jdoc:include type="component" />
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php if($this->getParam('mainbody_subpage', 'only_component') == 'only_component') : ?>    
            <div id="gkComponent">
                <jdoc:include type="component" />
            </div>
            <?php elseif($this->getParam('mainbody_subpage', 'only_component') == 'mainbody_before_component') : ?>
            <div id="gkComponent">
                <jdoc:include type="component" />
            </div>
            <?php else : ?>
            <div id="gkComponent">
                <jdoc:include type="component" />
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>                 
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Maybe I am an Idiot, but all this if-else seems to be doing the same.

Any help of how to remove the code creating duplication will be very much appreciated,

Help a dime in distress :)

Comment: Please contact the Gavick Pro developers as it's regarding their software

Comment: I tried, One needs to buy subscription for that. So I am fixing the code myself

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not an idiot, as for the person that wrote that `if` well… that's another story.
2. Let me re-write that `gkMainbodyWrap` for you:

*hmmm*…

```
<div id="gkMainbody" class="gkMain">
    <div id="gkMainbodyWrap">
        <div id="gkComponent">
            <jdoc:include type="component" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

3. The `<gavern:mobile>` and `<gavern:desktop>` tags are probably intended to be processed by their template framework/code base and are probably meant to act as a switching mechanism of some sort, like a basic type of [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) (aka [Adaptive web design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_web_design)). So, possibly JTouch is interfering with the Gavick code.
4. Last I looked JTouch was a mobile adaptive/reactive solution not a [responsive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) one, and those `gavern` tags look like an attempt at adaptive block markers, is it possible that the template while not responsive is actually adaptive?

Comment: Thank you so much for building up my confidence :) the gavick template has some iPhone,android and handheld layouts, but they are not so good. so I use Jtouch for mobile.